# What is the -file argument for AWS EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'm launching an EMR cluster through the console.

The console automatically added `-files s3://jmilloy/milp_mapper.py` in the Arguments field, which is the location I supplied for the mapper. I can't find the `-file` option documented anywhere. What does it do? Why was it added automatically? What happens if I remove it? Can I put other files from S3 that my script needs there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer:

`-files` is not a EMR flag rather it is a way to add files to the [Distributed Cache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html).

Long Version:

Hadoop uses something called as [GenricOptionsParser](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html) which is used to parse command line options. When you are using python for writing mapper or reducers which means that Hadoop is using something called as [Streaming API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) to run the job. So, when you are running a Streaming Job you have to pass in the path where your Mapper and Reducers are located in the filesystem (this could also be S3) using `-files` command line option, once you do so Hadoop will copy the files over to HDFS and then will copy them to Mappers and Reducers so that they could initialize your Python external processes.

If you don't specify your python mapper or reducer code using `-files` the job will fail.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm curious to try adding additional files that the mapper uses (2 binaries) this way, instead of through a bootstrap action.

Comment: Are those binaries libraries or are those python scripts as well that you want to call from your Mapper or Reducer python code ?

Comment: They are executables that I call as a subprocess. Any tips? They work on my test EC2 instance, but I haven't successfully gotten results through EMR yet.

Comment: You could try adding the files to DistributedCache and then they will be accessible from Mapper and Reducer from their current working directory. Take a look at this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-input-distributed-cache.html

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need! Didn't you say above that `-files` adds files to the DistributedCache? If so, what's the difference between `-files` and `-cacheFile`?

Comment: It seems like `-cacheFile` is a streaming-jar command line option to add file to DistributedCache but it is being [deprecated](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/e1109fb65608a668cd53dc324dadc6f63a74eeb9/hadoop-tools/hadoop-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/StreamJob.java#L345) so in future you have to use `-files`.